# What is the easiest way to test multi-threading in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a .cpp file which executes a test. I have compiled it into a bin. It works correctly.

I have been asked to test running this test in parallel on two cores of my processor in parallel.

How can I most easily and effectively do this?

Can I just run .`/Test1 0 && ./Test1 1` from my Linux terminal?

How can I make the parameters 0 and 1 in the above refer to the core which the test should execute on?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to test multi-threading or multi-processing ?

Comment: if you want to run test1 and test2 in parallel do `./test1 &; ./test2` or `./test1 &; ./test2 &`

Comment: The command you suggest runs 2 processes. Threads run within a single process.

Comment: `I have compiled it into a bin.` it seems you have 2 bins, test1 and test 2

Comment: if you wrote a multithreaded program then I'd rather expect that you have one executable `Test` that uses multiple threads. In your example it is unclear what `Test1` and `Test2` are or whether there is any interaction between them

Comment: @bruno multi-processing. I want to execute at the same time on different cores.

Comment: multi-processing doesn't guarantee core exclusion. Do you want to execute them at the same time, as different processes, on a specific processor core? Or do you wan to just execute them concurrently? Why are processing cores relevant? What should happen on a cpu with a single core? Do you want to execute the processes from C++ or from "your linux terminal"?

Comment: I have updated the test example. One test, which I want to run in parallel on 2 cores.

Comment: so as I said do `./test1 0 &; ./test1 1` or `./test1 0 &; ./test1 1 &` because `./Test1 0 && ./Test1 1 `  execute `test1 0` **then** may be `test1 1` depending on exit value of the first execution